# Dropbox file download fails

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to download a file from dropbox using the dropbox sdk for android.

I added the following permission in to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Following is the code I am using to download the file:

```
File mFile=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
try {
    FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream=new FileOutputStream(mFile);
    DropboxFileInfo mDropboxFileInfo=mDropboxAPI.getFile("/"+filename, null, mFileOutputStream, null);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DropboxException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Why does it fail, what error do are you getting ?

Comment: there was a problem the sd card path i am giving .
Please see the answer below given by vipul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing only directory name in your `mFile`variable.
I think you should append a file name after your directory path. This will resolve your problem.